# How can I assign multiple colors to tick labels in plots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to color a single number (or a set of numbers) on one of the axes in MATLAB?

Suppose I have a plot:

```
plot(1:10, rand(1,10))
```

Now, can I e.g. make the number 3 on the x-axis red?

Comment: Is it the x-tick label that you want to modify?

Comment: Yes, it is the x-tick label.

Comment: Please see the second part of the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532176/how-to-add-marker-to-matlab-colorbar/16532405#16532405) - you should be able to modify that to change the colour of a single tick instead of making it bold (and use it on a normal axes instead of a colorbar).

Comment: FYI in wakja's linked question, the color property to set will be `XColor`. This isn't the greatest solution though, since you're just overlaying another set of axes on top of the original, rather than editing just the axes label.

Comment: Maybe this is cheating, but the simplest method is to make a pdf and then edit this e.g. in Adobe Illustrator. Matlab plots usually require touching up to be publication quality, anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot have multiple colors for tick labels in one axes object. However, there's a solution (inspired by [this page from MathWorks support site](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PAYMC/?solution=1-1PAYMC)) that achieves the same effect. It overlays the existing axes it with another axes that has only one red tick.

Here's an example:

```
figure
plot(1:10, rand(1,10))
ax2 = copyobj(gca, gcf);                             %// Create a copy the axes
set(ax2, 'XTick', 3, 'XColor', 'r', 'Color', 'none') %// Keep only one red tick
ax3 = copyobj(gca, gcf);                             %// Create another copy
set(ax3, 'XTick', [], 'Color', 'none')               %// Keep only the gridline
```

The result is:

[image: result]

Comment: +1 beat me to the punch :P BTW, realised you can do this without copying the contents of the axes as well, by setting `'Color'` to none, and then giving the overlaid axes an empty `'YLim'` and the same `'XLim'`.

Comment: @wakjah I'm not following, which object do I need to set `'Color'` for?

Comment: Rather than doing a `copyobj`, you can just create a second `axes`, and set the `Color` on that; setting it to `'none'` will make the background transparent.

Comment: @wakjah I prefer copying, otherwise you'll need to synchronize the axes (_e.g_ with `linkaxes`) so they overlap correctly. Thanks for reminding me about `'Color'` though, I've noticed that my tick marks disappeared, and setting this to `'none'` fixes it :)

Comment: Thanks so much!! Do you know how I can get black vertical grid lines? I can't make them black without messing up the tick labels. (In case there was any doubt: the vertical grid is red, and the horizontal one is black).

Comment: @RobertP. Did you try doing the same procedure for 'YColor' and 'YTick'?

Comment: I haven't done anything with `YColor`. I don't see how `YColor` can affect the vertical grid lines (I guess they "belong" to the X-axis)? I tried adding something like:
`ax4 = copyobj(gca, gcf); % set(ax4, 'Xgrid','on','XColor','black','XTick', []))`, without any luck.

Comment: @RobertP. Oh, so you're asking about the x-axis ticks themselves?

Comment: @EitanT. I'm looking for what normally appears from `set(gca,'XGrid','on')`. I just figured out that it actually works on your code above, but I couldn't get it to work on my (a bit more complicated) code. I'm not at work anymore, so I can't check it until tomorrow, but I guess I'll figure it out =) Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

Single tick labels can be colored using [`tex` markup](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html), which is enabled for tick labels by default. It is defined in the `TickLabelInterpreter` property of the axis.

It provides two commands for coloring text:

- `\color{<name>}`, where `<name>` is a color name like “red” or “green“, and
- `\color[rgb]{<R>,<G>,<B>}`, where `<R>`, `<G>` and `<B>` are numbers between 0 and 1 and define an RGB color.

These commands can be used to color single tick labels:

```matlab
plot(1:10, rand(1,10))
ax = gca;

% Simply color an XTickLabel
ax.XTickLabel{3} = ['\color{red}' ax.XTickLabel{3}];

% Use TeX symbols
ax.XTickLabel{4} = '\color{blue} \uparrow';

% Use multiple colors in one XTickLabel
ax.XTickLabel{5} = '\color[rgb]{0,1,0}green\color{orange}?';

% Color YTickLabels with colormap
nColors = numel(ax.YTickLabel);
cm = jet(nColors);
for i = 1:nColors
    ax.YTickLabel{i} = sprintf('\\color[rgb]{%f,%f,%f}%s', ...
        cm(i,:), ax.YTickLabel{i});
end
```

And this is how the result looks:

[image: result]

The code worked for me in MATLAB R2016b and R2017a.

Comment: This looks awesome! I can't test it though, since I no longer have MATLAB. :(

Comment: That's quite neat indeed. As with many new handy graphic features, this only works for HG2 of course, so for MATLAB versions >= R2014b.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to copying the entire axes contents, it is possible to do this also by creating additional `axes` objects:

```
ax = axes();
p = plot(1:10, rand(1,10));
myTick = 3;

% Create new axes with transparent backgrounds
ax2 = axes();
ax3 = axes();
set([ax2 ax3], 'XLim', xlim(ax));
set([ax2 ax3], 'Color', 'none');

set(ax3, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);

% Give one new axes a single tick mark
set(ax2, 'YTick', []);
set(ax2, 'XTick', myTick);
set(ax2, 'XColor', 'r');

 % This line is necessary to use the plot toolbar functions like zoom / pan
linkaxes([ax ax2 ax3]);
```

Comment: +1: you don't need `linkaxes` if you're setting the `XLim` manually ;)

Comment: You do if you want to use the toolbar's zoom :)

Comment: Right :) Also, you can do `xlim(ax)` instead of `get(ax, 'XLim')`, it's shorter.