# Matlab - plot - How to get the x-axis labels in a color keeping the x-axis color black and the first tick value hidden?

Tags: matlab, plot

**How to get the xaxis labels 2 4 6 in blue keeping the x-axis color black and the first tick value hidden?**

when I am trying to change the tick label color the tick labels disappear

[image]

```
x=0:0.25:5
y=sin(x)

ax1 = subplot(1,2,1) ;
plot(x,y)
set(gca, 'YAxisLocation', 'right')
xlabel('x','Color','b')
ylabel('y')
%set(gca,'xColor','k');
%set(gca,'xticklabel','b')
Q=get(gca,'xtick');
R=get(gca,'xticklabel');
set(gca,'xtick',Q(2:end))
set(gca,'xticklabel',R(2:end,:))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [the undocumented `XRuler` property](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-rulers) of the axis:

```
h = gca;
h.XRuler.TickLabels.ColorData = uint8([0;0;255;255]);
```

Note this might not be available in older versions of MATLAB, it works for me on 2015a

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16677119/5471520), I decided to try and solve your problem in a similar manner. I was able to find a working solution, but it's not pretty as you need to copy several axes objects, and it seems that it's not robust to resizing of the figure. Hopefully it will still be helpful!

The code is below.

```
%//Original code
x=0:0.25:5;
y=sin(x);
ax1 = subplot(1,2,1);
plot(x,y)
set(ax1, 'YAxisLocation', 'right')
ylabel(ax1, 'y');
xlabel(ax1, 'x', 'Color', 'b'); %// Give the blue 'x' as label

%//Solution
my_xticks = [2 4 6]; %// The XTicks you want to show
drawnow; %//Must draw the axes here due to YAxisLocation, otherwise will not work
ax2 = copyobj(ax1, gcf); %// Create a copy the axes
set(ax2, 'XTick', my_xticks, 'XColor', 'b', 'Color', 'none') %// Keep only my_xticks in blue
ax3 = copyobj(ax1, gcf);  %// Create another copy...
set(ax3, 'XTick', [], 'Color', 'none'); %// From which we keep only the black gridline
xlabel(ax3, ''); %// Remove the xlabel from ax3 (would show x in wrong position)
set(ax1, 'xtick', my_xticks); %// In ax1, show black ticks at desired locations
```

End result looks like this:
[image]

Caveats, as mentioned: You are copying the axes object twice, which is wasteful. If you resize the figure, the construction seems to implode. I could not figure out how to fix these.