# Matlab Scatter Plot (multiple y values)

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to make a plot with multiple y-values for a single x-value. The code that I have been using plots this in two separate axes.

```
in = {[26 171 40], [34 32 104 28]}
titles = {'Locker','9u'}
for i  = 1:length(in)
    subplot(1,length(in), i);
    scatter(ones(1,length(in{i})), in{i},'filled')
    set(gca,'XTick',[])
    xlabel(titles{i});
end
```

How can I plot my data in a single axes? I am not very experienced at using Matlab.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot at different x locations, by multiplying the vector with ones by `i`. And then set the xticks, labels and axis limits appropriately.

As for the colors, you can make a `length(in)`-by-3 matrix containing the rgb values per category of data. Then provide the appropriate row of this matrix to `scatter` in the loop.

```
in = {[26 171 40], [34 32 104 28], randi(200, 5,1), randi(150, 3,1)};
titles = {'Locker','9u', 'A', 'B'};
category_colors = [
    1, 0, 0; % color for 'Locker'
    1, 0, 0; % '9u'
    0, 0, 1; % 'A'
    0, 0, 1; % 'B'
    ];

figure(1); clf;
hold on;
for i  = 1:length(in)
    scatter(ones(1,length(in{i}))*i, in{i},[], category_colors(i,:), 'filled'); % multiply ones with i 
end
set(gca,'XTick',1:length(in));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', titles);
xlim([0.5 length(in)+0.5])
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! One quick question: how can I adjust the colours for each xtick (e.g. if I would like 9u to be blue, or Locker to be read)?

Comment: There are two good solutions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676668/how-can-i-assign-multiple-colors-to-tick-labels-in-plots-in-matlab), as suggested there you can use the tex markup. Just change `titles = {'\color{red}Locker','\color{blue}9u'}`

Comment: Sure, google is your friend, first hit of 'matlab ticklabels rotation': https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xtickangle.html

Comment: Thanks! Oh and for my initial comment, I wished to make the data points different colour (sorry, I should have explained myself better). Is this easily fixed?

Comment: Ah, yeah sure, look at the [`scatter` docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#btrj9jn-1-c), you can provide a color matrix (size: number of datapoints by 3) with rgb values.

Comment: I am still having a bit of trouble. I also searched through mathworks (e.g. https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/278368-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-single-data-point-of-a-scatter-plot-by-using-handles) to work it out, but I haven't been successful. I have 36 x-values, and I am trying to make the first x-value one colour, the following 19 values a different colour, and the remaining x-values another different colour. Is there a simple way just like the xticks example?

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62674097/edit) your question to be a bit more specific about how to color the data points? Maybe generate some additional data (`rand`)  and clearly describe what you want to be colored.

Comment: Sure. Apologies, they must have sounded confusing. Consider the plot in your post, with two xticks 'Locker' and '9U'. But say you add two more xticks to your plot, call these 'A' and 'B'. Is it possible to change the colour of the first two datapoints corresponding to 'Locker' and '9U', to distinguish these datapoints from those corresponding to 'A' and 'B'. Is this clearer?

Comment: I made an image in my original post of what I mean :)

Comment: May God bless your soul. This has helped a lot!