# Plotting a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a cell `fit1`, which is of dimension `50x1`.

Every entry of the cell is a matrix `52x50`.

When I plot it:

```
for ii=1:k
    hold On
    plot(fit1{ii},'b')
    xlim([-1100,5000])
    ylim([-5,20])
    legend('hide')
end
```

I get:

[image: pic1]

Now I want to do 2 things:

1. First of all I want to mark certain areas of the plot:
   for example in the between `x=-1000` and `x=0` the background color should be yellow, between `x=0` and `x=100` it should be red etc.
2. I want to draw some vertical lines - for example at `x=189`.
3. Is there a possibility to mark the x-axis in certain colors instead of the background?

when I use the suggestion I get:

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKJhe.png)

Comment: Please limit each post to a single question. Each of your three questions has been answered here before, please use Google to search for answers before asking.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Using the `patch()` function might suffice to change the appearance of the background. The `patch()` function takes two arrays describing the coordinate pairs of the polygon to be drawn/filled. To draw the vertical lines the `line()` function can be used. The `line()` function also takes two arrays representing the coordinate pairs that describe were the line begins and ends. Here is a question/answer going over your third point: [How can I assign multiple colors to tick labels in plots in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676668/how-can-i-assign-multiple-colors-to-tick-labels-in-plots-in-matlab).

[image: Plot Background Color Change]

```
clf;
xlim([-1100,5000]);
ylim([-5,20]);
hold on

%Yellow background%
X_Minimum = -1100; X_Maximum = 0;
patch([X_Minimum X_Maximum X_Maximum X_Minimum], [min(ylim) min(ylim) max(ylim) max(ylim)],'y','EdgeColor','none')

%Red background%
X_Minimum = 0; X_Maximum = 100;
patch([X_Minimum X_Maximum X_Maximum X_Minimum], [min(ylim) min(ylim) max(ylim) max(ylim)],'r','EdgeColor','none')

%Vertical line%
X_Value = 189;
line([X_Value X_Value],[min(ylim) max(ylim)],'color','k');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when I use your code, then the patch overlaps the "initial" plot - so I only see the last "run" of the for loop and the rest is not visible due to the patch

Comment: If you place the patch before the for-loop I think it should work.